# what does setting PATH do on OSx?

Tags: path

I'm trying to install mysql with django on my mac and a tutorial is saying i have to:

```
Add /usr/local/mysql/bin/ to PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/:$PATH
(from my ~/.bashrc)
```

I know setting paths help find executables, but i know you can set multiple paths in your bash profile.  how does this work?

Answer (score 1):

> I know setting paths help find executables

When you type `foo`, it looks for an executable called `foo` in each directory in the path in turn.

> but i know you can set multiple paths in your bash profile. how does this work?

You can set only one PATH variable. It contains a colon separated list of directories that will be checked.